# What combination of Block Public Access settings makes my s3 bucket viewable to everyone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and created an s3 bucket for static site hosting.  I want to allow Read-Only access to everyone so they can access the website.  What combination of settings gives me this scenario?  Do I need to uncheck all 4 settings in the Block Public Access settings?  Do I even need to add a bucket policy if all 4 settings are set to off?  I just want to make sure the bucket is never written to but the account holder.  Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Block Public Access acts as an *additional* layer of protection to prevent Amazon S3 buckets from being made public accidentally.

By default, all content in Amazon S3 is private. You can then make content accessible in several different ways:

- At the bucket-level, by creating a **Bucket Policy** on the desired bucket. The rules added to this bucket can be used to grant access to objects (`GetObject`), list contents, upload, delete, etc. The policies can also get quite specific, such as allowing access only to specific IP addresses.
- At the object-level, by configuring **Access Control Lists (ACLs)** on each individual object. For example, an object can be made publicly accessible.
- At the IAM User or IAM Group level, by adding an **IAM Policy** directly the to the user/group. This is great for granting access to only specific sets of IAM users (as opposed to publicly).
- By using **Pre-Signed URLs** that are generated programmatically and provide time-limited access to a specific object. This is typically used by applications to grant access to private objects. For example, a photo-sharing website would keep all photos private, but an authorized user would be able to view their own pictures, or pictures shared with them via the application.

So, in your question, you say you would like to "allow Read-Only access to everyone so they can access the website". This would normally be done by creating a **Bucket Policy** such as:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"MakeItPublic",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You should first deactivate the two Block Public Access settings that refer to Bucket Policies (the bottom two).

Comment: To make the bucket policy work, I think only the last option needs to be deactivated i.e. "Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies"

Comment: Yes, but to add the policy you have to first deactivate the bottom two, add the bucket policy, then reactivate the second to last setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need Amazon CloudFront distribution. In addition to providing the benefits of an integrated CDN, you can configure an Origin Access Identity that ensures that the bucket can only be accessed through CloudFront, not through public S3.

Client -> Route53 -> Cloudfront -> S3 (blocked public access)

**In Cloudfront**

- Create cloudfront function (from left menu), this will redirect any
  request with index.html appended. For ex: example.com/home to
  example.com/home/index.html

  ```
  'use strict';
  function handler(event) {
   var request = event.request;
   var uri = request.uri;

   // Check whether the URI is missing a file name.
   if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
       request.uri += 'index.html';
   } 
   // Check whether the URI is missing a file extension.
   else if (!uri.includes('.')) {
       request.uri += '/index.html';
   }
    return request;
  }
  ```
- Create the origin access (from left menu), this will be used in
  distribution's origin
- In Distributions

  - In origin tab

    - Create origin as S3 type, by choosing the s3 bucket
    - Click on origin access control settings that create at first step
  - Edit general settings and put index.html in default root object.
  - Edit Behaviours, In Function associations, select cloudfront function
    in viewer request. Don’t need to go with lambda function

**In S3**

- In properties, disable static s3 website hosting
- In permissions

  - Block all public access
  - Edit the bucket policy with below:

    ```
    {
       "Version": "2008-10-17",
       "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
       "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::ACC_NUMBER:distribution/DISTRIBUTION_ID"
                }
            }
        }
       ]
    }
    ```

**In Route53**

- Create A record by selecting cloudfront distribution